# SAS: Creating separate histograms on one page and producing plot for value combinations

Tags: statistics, sas, histogram

Column 1:
Flu Shot Status

Column 2:
Age

Column 3:
Health Awareness Index

Column 4:
Gender

```
   0    59    52    0
   0    61    55    1
   1    82    51    0
   0    51    70    0
   0    53    70    0
   0    62    49    1
   0    51    69    1
   0    70    54    1
   0    71    65    1
   0    55    58    1
   0    58    48    0
   0    53    58    1
   0    72    65    0
   0    56    68    0
   0    56    83    0
```

That's my dataset above and what I want to do is the following 
a) Produce a single plot of Health Awareness Index (HAI) and Age for each value combination of Gender and Flu Shot Status and

(I'm not so sure how to do this at all; a few hints about where to start would really help)

b) Produce separate histograms for the variable Health Awareness Index by Flu Shot Status for Males between the Ages of 50 and 70 (including both 50 and 70). Give the histogram a title and color the bars using different colors for each histogram.  Here's my code:

First I will set up a permanent library, as the dataset is titled hw3data.sas:

```
 libname di “c:\flu”;
 data di.HW3 Data;
 infile hw3data.sas;
 input FluShotStatus Age HAI Gender;
 run;

 proc sort data=di.hw3
 by age;
 run;

 data=di.hw3
 if age=50 to 70
 run;

 proc univariate data=Steel;
  var HAI FluShotStatus;
  histogram FluShotStatus;
  run;
```

I'm not so sure how to insert the normal distribution curve here and I guess I could really use some help

Comment: You should really break your questions down and ask a single question at a time. You'll get faster responses, and it also helps to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't clearly specify what type of plot you're looking for, so I'm going to assume at this point you're looking for a scatter plot, by age and gender combinations. Here's an example that utilizes PROC SGPLOT which is a good graphical procedure for generating SAS graphs.

```
data have;
input flu age hai gender;
cards;
   0    59    52    0
   0    61    55    1
   1    82    51    0
   0    51    70    0
   0    53    70    0
   0    62    49    1
   0    51    69    1
   0    70    54    1
   0    71    65    1
   0    55    58    1
   0    58    48    0
   0    53    58    1
   0    72    65    0
   0    56    68    0
   0    56    83    0
  ;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by flu gender;
run;

proc sgplot data=have;
by flu gender;
scatter x=age y=hai;
label age='Age' hai='Health Awareness Index';
run;quit;
```